# Stuck at login - create account

Tags: feature-request, login, google

So I hit the Log-In button. Then choose "Google" as the authentication provider. I had an email pre-set. Unfortunately I did not realize it was the wrong one. So I get an offer to set up my new account.
Now I'm stuck at that page. I had to clear all application data. Because even if I restart the process I'm immediately offered to open a new account.

Simply put, please put a "cancel" button on that page.

Comment: I couldn't see why you should not put a cancel button there or a back button.

Comment: Looks like only the happy path was tested.

Comment: Really annoying getting stuck in there, having to go to gmail, delete all cookies, going back to SO, going back to login at Google,... please fix this issue its a trap

Comment: This happened to me as well. Clearing SO cookies wasn't working - thanks to Daniel's comment I figured out you have to clear some google cookies.